# Cookie authentication on Cloudant throwing exception

Tags: objective-c, couchdb, cloudant, ibm-cloud

I have list of users in the `_users` DB in Cloudant. When I try to authenticate by cookie authentication sending a POST request to the `/_session` API end point as below:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/_session";


NSMutableURLRequest *parseRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSMutableDictionary *postDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSError *error;
[postDictionary setValue:@"userinDB" forKey:@"name"];
[postDictionary setValue:@"passowrdinDB" forKey:@"password"];

NSData *postBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

[parseRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[parseRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[parseRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:parseRequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           if (connectionError) {
                               NSLog(@"error:%@",connectionError);
                           }
                           else {
                               NSLog(@"response:%@",response);
                           }
                       }];
```

It is throwing the following exception:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"user accounts must have a username"}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `application/json` content-type instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` since that's what you are using.

Comment: Understood i have to post username and password with in url and i need to set content-type:x-www-formurl encoded.so do you have any idea.how to POST with above case.

Comment: You can use JSON, just set the correct content-type.

Comment: Or if you prefer you can pass the name and password as a query in the URL. Just make sure the URL-encode them properly.

Comment: I have tried using json but again its throwing same exception and In clodant docs they mentioned to use content type as url encoded.so can you guide me how to pass username and password in url encoded.